# “Advective”, “diffusive”, “dispersive”, and related terms in the realm of PDEs

Tags: partial-differential-equations, terminology

Whenever I read a paper involving PDEs, the discussion inevitably refers to “the dispersive term” or “the advective term” or similar. From context it is usually possible to figure out the antecedent, but I have not been able to find a glossary of these terms anywhere.

My question:

- What exactly do terms like “diffusive” and “dispersive” refer to?

And a bonus question:

- What intuition can be had about how these different terms behave?

Comment: In short, "Diffusive" means the spatial spread out of something (wave, density, etc), and dispersion is similar to diffusion, yet it is the spread out of the frequency so that quantities are propagating at different speeds (mostly likely depend on the spatial variable). I don't usually see the term "the dispersive term", because dispersion is rather from the intrinsic property of the solution rather than a term, e.g. you can say in Klein-Gordon equation, adding that zeroth order damping term makes the solution shows dispersive behavior. But call that term "dispersive" is unreasonable to me.

Comment: Advection term, which normally is given in the form of $\mathbf{b}\cdot \nabla u$, roughly speaking, describes some density $u$ changes along with some flow $\mathbf{b}$. It comes from the flux $\mathbf{F}=\mathbf{b}u$ (constitutive law) and the conservation of mass $\partial_t u + \nabla \cdot \mathbf{F} = 0$ if no source of the substance, which that density $u$ measures spatially, is present.